# Entity Framework and WCF Data Services : Calling business logic after persisting entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

We have an Entity Data Model which is used by a WCF Data Service that needs to run some business logic after persisting an entity to the database.  In this case it needs to pass the id generated for the persisted entity to another service via a WCF web service call.

The question is how do we run some business logic after saving the entity.  Part of this business logic will be a call to another web service with the generated id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On case anyone is wondering, the SaveChanges method is virtual and so can be overriden.  The id of the saved entity can be obtained after the base.SaveChanges() call and the web service call made or event raised.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, perhaps I am not understanding the question properly, but could you not simply use an interceptor?

[Interceptors (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer.  We've looked at interceptors but there's no interceptor that will run after you've saved an entity to the database.  You can intercept a request to change an entity (update, change etc) but not fire some code after the actual change.  We'd need to do this as we only have the new id after saving it.

Answer (score 0):

I might look at publishing a message to a transactional queue, inside the same transaction as EF is using.  That way, you can be guaranteed that either both the data is persisted and the business process is kicked off, or neither is.

You can even have your entity publish the message to the queue when you call the operation on the entity that should trigger the business process.  The message will not be published until the entire transaction commits.

NServiceBus or MassTransit can help with this.